# How to remove the Unity8's System Settings?

Tags: unity, system-settings, unity8

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 today and have removed the Unity 8 session and Mir from the system. Now I am seeing the Unity 8's System Settings remaining. How to remove it from the system as it's useless?